# Is SharePoint uses indexing service of windows?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, indexing, document, indexing-service

Let me know if it uses built-in service or has own service for search in documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Sharepoint uses it's own algorithm for document search, since Windows Indexing Service doesn't have support for file versions, history and such stuff, Sharepoint uses it's own service. But both services can coexist and operate on the same server.